# How can I add 30 mintutes to time picker in android?

Tags: android

In my application I have 2 time picker dialogs. In that if I change the time from 1st picker I want to add 30 minutes interval to second picker. For e.g if set time in 1st picker as 11.00 AM then 2nd should show time 11.30 AM.

How can I achieve this?

```
TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener listenerTime = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                Date date = new Date();
                if (m_bSimafor) {

                    date.setTime(m_StartDate.getTime());
                    date.setHours(hourOfDay);
                    date.setMinutes(minute);

                    long delta = 0;
                    delta = m_StartDate.getTime() - date.getTime();

                    m_StartDate.setHours(date.getHours());
                    m_StartDate.setMinutes(date.getMinutes());


                    //m_EndDate.setTime(m_EndDate.getTime() - (delta / 2));
                } else {
                    date.setTime(m_EndDate.getTime());
                    date.setHours(hourOfDay);
                    date.setMinutes(minute);

                    if (m_StartDate.getTime() > date.getTime()) {
                        String strMessage = "The end date must be after the start date.";
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(m_Context, strMessage,
                                strMessage.length());
                        toast.show();
                        m_EndDate.setTime(m_StartDate.getTime());
                    } else {
                        m_EndDate.setTime(date.getTime());
                    }
                }
                setDateAndTime();
            }
```

Comment: paste your code of approach... I mean, how u need to show those two time pickers

Comment: @Anil...i want to add 30 min value in 2nd picker when change value in 1st

Comment: On setting first timer, call the second timer with adding 30 to minutes field... still problem means, post ur code at anilcse003@gmail.com